# PHP - opening and editing a large text file

Tags: php

I want to use php to open a (rather large, ~ 500 lines) text file, but I only need to rewrite the second line of text file anytime I run the PHP command.

My question is:

1) Does opening a 500 lines text file take a toll on the server's performance?

2) If yes, is there a way to just read the first 3 - 4 lines to edit it?

Thank you.

Comment: A 500 line text file is nothing.. How often is it being opened / wrote to?

Comment: I guess it's not very often (imagining bi-weekly rate here).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance issues then. I'd just slurp the whole file into memory, make your changes, and then overwrite the file with the changes.

Comment: whats in the file - there may be a better idea ? - what about a db? or splitting the file up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500 Lines is nothing for the server to handle. Here are some benchmarks for you. The tests were done on a local dev environment with the following:

```
Windows 7
Core i3 530 @ 2.93GHz
4GB RAM
```

Here is the 5 tests I ran for fetching and printing with `500` lines:

```
Rendered in 0.0010001659 seconds using 17KB of memory.
Rendered in 0.0009999275 seconds using 17 KB of memory.
Rendered in 0.0009999275 seconds using 17 KB of memory.
Rendered in 0.0009999275 seconds using 17 KB of memory.
Rendered in 0.0009999275 seconds using 17 KB of memory.
```

To prove it isn't as intensive as you think it is, heres a test with `10,500` lines:

```
Rendered in 0.0009999275 seconds using 343 KB of memory.
Rendered in 0.0009999275 seconds using 343 KB of memory.
Rendered in 0 seconds using 343 KB of memory.
Rendered in 0.0009999275 seconds using 343 KB of memory.
Rendered in 0.0010001659 seconds using 343 KB of memory.
```

So as you can see, it's a marginal use of resources. If you're interested, here's the code that was used to test:

```
//Log current time so we can tell how long it takes to run this script
define('START_TIME', microtime(true));
//Log starting memory useage
define('START_MEMORY_USAGE', memory_get_usage());


$file = 'derp.txt';
$data = file_get_contents($file);
print_r($data);


$time = round((microtime(true) - START_TIME), 10);
$memory = round((memory_get_usage() - START_MEMORY_USAGE) / 1024);
echo 'Rendered in <strong><u>' . $time . '</u></strong> seconds using <strong><u>' . $memory . '</u></strong> KB of memory.';
```

---

To understand your issues more, what is stored in the text file? Just lines of text? I'd suggest doing what [@Dagon stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292951/php-opening-and-editing-a-large-text-file/30293369#comment48682562_30292951).

Comment: It's actually a python script to be executed on the Terminal, so I think I would try to keep the file as intact as possible

Answer (score 2):

Like Darren wrote (good answere), its not expensive. But if you get really large files and are not able to use a database or similar storage-systems you can try the `fget`-function form PHP that uses file-pointers and is able to read one line at a moment.

[PHP: fgets - Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Comment: Great idea with the `fget-` @Jan!